# pre_get_posts improperly searching revisions

Tags: search, pre-get-posts

I have a `pre_get_posts()` function that is used by my users to search posts. I've noticed that for whatever reason it seems to be searching text within a post's previous revision that is no longer in the post and return the current post.

**ROUGH EXAMPLE:**

```
Previous Revision Title = "I like to analyze"
Current Title = "I like to report"
```

Now if you search for "analyze" it would return the post with the `Current Title` which I would prefer it not to.

I've setup the query in a way I thought would remove this...but it's not:

```
$search_post_types_array = array('zr_td','st_kb','forum','topic','reply');
$query->set('post_type', $search_post_types_array);
$query->set('post_status', 'publish');
$query->set('post_parent', 0);
```

Please let me know if you need additional clarification or information.

SQL from `$wp_query->request;`

> SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN
>   wp_postmeta AS m ON (wp_posts.ID = m.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( (
>   wp_posts.post_parent = 0 AND (((((wp_posts.post_title LIKE
>   '%analytics%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%analytics%'))) OR
>   ((m.meta_value LIKE '%analytics%')) )) AND wp_posts.post_type IN
>   ('zr_td', 'st_kb', 'forum', 'topic', 'reply') AND
>   ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))) AND post_type != 'revision') AND
>   post_status != 'future' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE
>   '{a2ab97c8fd44df4b50f3dc2108b2651d7e3390dcacd7fd0413334d3fd0287ce9}analytics{a2ab97c8fd44df4b50f3dc2108b2651d7e3390dcacd7fd0413334d3fd0287ce9}'
>   DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: Have you tried setting the post_type explicitly? Also, can you add the SQL actually being run ($wp_query->request)?

Comment: Can you show how SQL looks like?

Comment: I do set the post types explictly; I have updated the original question with it

Comment: @motivast I have added the SQL...I think that is running

Comment: Do you see that you are searching also in `meta_value` of each post? Can you confirm that there is no `analyze` value in posts like `"I like to report"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it thanks for the investigation tips guys!

So when it was doing the `meta_value` search the search term was showing up the meta_key `_wp_old_slug`'s meta_value